# UDP Stats Response From Game Server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, udp

First of all Thank You for taking time and reading this through. As i'm a new student to VB.NET i need Help.

I'm sending command to UDP game server "`\status\`" to get information on Dedicated Server. Now i can send the command but i can't receive the response from the game server. I want exact response from the game server in return as the Wireshark.

**Response Captured by Wireshark**
[image: WireShark]

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
 Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Text.Encoding
    Imports System.Text

    Public Class Form1
        Dim publisher As New Sockets.UdpClient(9398)
        Dim subscriber As New Sockets.UdpClient(9399)


        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            publisher.Connect(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
            Dim sendbytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox3.Text)
            publisher.Send(sendbytes, sendbytes.Length)
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            subscriber.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 100
            subscriber.Client.Blocking = False
            Try
                Dim ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
                Dim rcvbytes() As Byte = subscriber.Receive(ep)
                TextBox4.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

        End Sub

    End Class
```

**Program UI:**

[image: Form]

Comment: Based on your Wireshark capture the server sends its response back to the same port - 9398, but you're trying to receive data from 9399. You can use the same UdpClient for both sending and receiving, you don't need two of them. Also, you're trying to receive only once when the form loads. That won't work. You've got to check for a response after you've sent the data to the server, i.e. inside `Button1_Click`.

Comment: A socket can both send and receive.  Presently you have two connections (on port 9398 and 9399).  And you form is listening on port 26001,  You need to receive on same port that where data is sent.  You can create either one connection (one port) where both publisher and subscriber both send and receive.  Or you can have two connections where publisher sends on 9398 (subscriber receives on 9398) and subscriber sends on 9399 (publisher receives on 9399).

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your suggestion it worked... I just realized that i was making 2 UdpClients and asking 1st client to send data and asking 2nd client to receive without sending data to 2nd client.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution. It would be appreciated if you could share us your solution and then mark it as an answer.You help others find the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use [BeginReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?view=netframework-4.8)

and have your callback handle the data that arrives.

Then immediately redo your BeginReceive so that you are ready for any more data.

Receive only fires once so you would need to do a lot of loop handling for the data to arrive, and as it's only in your formload, it's finished before you send your request to the server.

Comment: Thanks for getting back... I will try this in near future to see how this works. For now the code i have worked.